System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' problem with blazor server app
I'm making my first blazor application and I'mrunning into an error, when I'm trying to get a specific User by Id.
for some contexts I'm using a Blazor server as frontend with a .NET 8 API as a backend
Blazor page code:
@page "/User"
@page "/User/{Id:int}"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@using System.Net.Http
@using Models
@using System.Text.Json;
@using System.Text
@using System.Security.Cryptography;
@inject HttpClient HttpClient
@inject NavigationManager NavManager


@if (Id == null)
{
    <h3>User Add</h3>
}
else
{
    <h3>User Edit</h3>
}

<form method="post" @onsubmit="AddUser" @formname="UserAdd" class="mt-4">
    <AntiforgeryToken />

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="name" class="form-label">Name:</label>
        <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="user!.Name" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Company" class="form-label">Company:</label>
        <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="user!.Company" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Department" class="form-label">Department:</label>
        <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="user!.Department" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email:</label>
        <InputText type="email" @bind-Value="user!.Email" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Password" class="form-label">Password:</label>
        <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="user!.Password" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public User? user { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (Id != null)
        {
            try{
                var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync($"https://localhost:7183/api/User/{Id}");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle error
                Console.WriteLine("Error getting user: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            user ??= new();
        }
    }

    void AddUser()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] salt = GenerateSalt();
            user.Password = HashPassword(user.Password, salt);

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7183/api/User");

            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(user);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = client.PostAsync("User", content).Result;

            NavManager.NavigateTo("/UserOverview");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle error
            Console.WriteLine("Error adding user: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private string HashPassword(string password, byte[] salt)
    {
        using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 10000))
        {
            byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(32); // 32 bytes for SHA256
            byte[] hashBytes = new byte[36]; // 32 bytes for hash + 4 bytes for salt

            Array.Copy(salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, 4);
            Array.Copy(hash, 0, hashBytes, 4, 32);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }
    }

    private byte[] GenerateSalt()
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[4]; // 4 bytes for salt
        using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rngCsp.GetBytes(salt);
        }
        return salt;
    }
}

And the API methode i have:
group.MapGet("/{id}", async Task<Results<Ok<User>, NotFound>> (int id, DataContext db) =>
{
    return await db.User.AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(model => model.Id == id)
        is User model
            ? TypedResults.Ok(model)
            : TypedResults.NotFound();
})
.WithName("GetUserById")
.WithOpenApi();

after the line:
var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync($"https://localhost:7183/api/User/{Id}");
i get this error message:
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=CalibrationReportingToolFrontend
  StackTrace:
   at CalibrationReportingToolFrontend.Components.Pages.OtherPages.UserAdd.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)

I thought maybe the Id i was looking for doesn't exist in the DB so i tried this:
var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:7183/api/User/6");
Beside that i also tested my API endpoint and this seems to be working as expected

Does this answer your question? What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?

You get the first Render when OnInitializedAsync does an await.  And then your user is still null.

@Fildor: that is indeed the canonical q+a for this exception. But first check if the problem is not very specific to a platform. In this case it is.

Well, it is what it is ... also: unrelated to this issue but var response = client.PostAsync("User", content).Result; - follow-up question incoming ... don't block on async code @JuleanCode.

I'm making my first blazor application  - how much C# have you done, in your life?

You're telling the compiler user is not null when you do this: user!.Name. But when the razor page is generating user very well may be null. Check for it before making any references to user.
@if(user is not null){
<form method="post" @onsubmit="AddUser" @formname="UserAdd" class="mt-4">
    <AntiforgeryToken />

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="name" class="form-label">Name:</label>
        <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="user!.Name" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Company" class="form-label">Company:</label>
        <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="user!.Company" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Department" class="form-label">Department:</label>
        <InputText type="text" @bind-Value="user!.Department" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email:</label>
        <InputText type="email" @bind-Value="user!.Email" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Password" class="form-label">Password:</label>
        <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="user!.Password" class="form-control" required />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
}


Ahh, what happened to the good old user != null days eh? Where did all this SQL come from in my C#? :)

By the way, mostly once you've checked that it isn't null, you shouldn't need to use the null forgiving operator. It might be worth giving the OP a quick lesson in "why you shouldnt just slap ! everywhere to shut the compiler up, when it was actively trying to help you avoid hitting the exact exception that just blew up your code"

thank you so much, I can't believe how i mussed something simple like this
